# Como checkar valor em enumerador com [Flags]?

Tags: c#, enums

Eu tenho meu enumerador:

```
[Flags]
public enum EConta {
   Receber = 1,
   Pagar = 2,
   Cobrada = 3,
   Atrazada = 4
}
```

e tenho a atribuição

```
EConta conta = EConta.Receber | EConta.Pagar;
var retorno = EConta.Cobrada
```

Como eu faço para comparar se na variável `conta` possui o valor da variável `retorno`?

Eu testei assim:

```
conta.HasFlag(retorno)
```

Não acontece erro, porém não funciona

O que há de errado ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que o método *HasFlag* funcione como o esperado o *enum* deverá simular a representação de um *byte* em *bits*. Cada elemento do *enum* deverá ter um valor correspondente a 2^n onde n é a sua posição no byte em representação binária.

Terá de alterar o seu enum para:

```
[Flags]
public enum EConta {
   none = 0,
   Receber = 1,
   Pagar = 2,
   Cobrada = 4,
   Atrazada = 8
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, e se caso eu precisar ter um outro valor no enum, o valor será 16 ? isso ?

Comment: Sim 16, 32, 64 etc, .